# Finding all homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

I want to find all group homomorphisms $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}/ m \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, with $m$ and $n$ natural numbers.

Clearly $\varphi(0)=0$ since the identity in $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ must map to the identity in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, and it follows that $m \varphi(1)=0$, so is $mx \equiv 0 \bmod n$?

This as far as I get. How can I find all the homomorphisms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that $\phi(1)$ must be some value $x$ in $Z/nZ$. And as you observe, $m$ times this value must be zero. So look for all values in $Z/nZ$ that have $mx = 0$ and these are the only possibilities for $\phi(1)$, which uniquely determines $\phi$.

The only thing that remains is to show that if $x$ is such a value, then $\phi(1) = x$ *does* define a homomorphism, but I'll bet you'll find tat's not too hard. Try if for $m = 6$, $n = 9$ to get a feel for things.

Comment: So if $m=6$ and $n=9$, then $\phi(1)=x$ can be either $3$ or $6$, right? How can I go about showing that this defines a homomorphism?

Comment: Well, for any $k \in Z/mZ$, you know $\phi(k) = k \phi(1) = kx$, so now you've got $\phi$ defined for $k = 0, 1, \ldots, m-1$. (You really need to show that if $p = q + mr$, where all items are integers, then $\phi(p) = \phi(q)$, i.e., that $kmr = 0 \bmod n$...but it does, so you're done.) Now you need to show $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$. That should not be so hard. Just to check: what part of this apparently "generic" proof *doesn't* work for the $m=6, n = 9$ case when you define $\phi(1) = 4$?

Comment: Ok I think I'm getting it, I've shown that $\phi(ab)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$. And if $\phi(1)$ is defined as 4 then 4m isn't congruent to 0 mod 9? And just to confirm, is the number of homomorphisms the number of values of x which satisfy the condition?

Comment: Yes, that's one fail. Also: $\phi(1) = 4$ means $\phi(7) = 28$ which is not congruent to $4$, mod $9$, i.e, $\phi$ is not well-defined on equivalence classes -- which is just another way of saying what you said. The number of homomorphisms is indeed the number of $x$ that satisfy the condition. Try it with pairs $(3, 5)$, $(5, 3)$, $(6, 8)$, $(6, 9)$, $(6, 12)$ and see if you can spot the pattern.